# Is there any workaround to implement YAML based pipelines for other git repositories in Azure Pipelines?

Tags: git, azure-devops, azure-pipelines-yaml

The YAML pipeline is not supported for "Other git repositories" in Azure Pipelines [as of June 4, 2022]. In our organization, we have a self-hosted Gitea server for managing source code. We want to implement YAML CI/CD pipelines using Azure Pipelines but it is not supported for other git repositories.

Is there any workaround to implement YAML pipelines for other git repositories in Azure Pipelines?

[Supported YAML pipelines in Azure Pipelines](https://i.stack.imgur.com/L97uZ.png)

Comment: what do you mean by it is not supported ? Looking at your screenshot it looks like it is supported.

Comment: A YAML editor opens by choosing Azure Repos, Bitbucket, and GitHub. When I tried with "Other git" option, the YAML editor is not available and it kept with the classic pipleline. In the attached screenshot, "YAML" text is highlighted for YAML-supported options. It is not available for "Other git" option and I could not find it in the later steps as well.

Answer (score 1):

> Is there any workaround to implement YAML based pipelines for other git repositories in Azure Pipelines?

According to the document [Supported source repositories](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/repos/?view=azure-devops)：

> YAML pipelines are a new form of pipelines that have been introduced
> in Azure DevOps Server 2019 and in Azure Pipelines. YAML pipelines
> only work with certain version control systems. The following table
> shows all the supported version control systems and the ones that
> support YAML pipelines.
>
> [image]

The Azure pipelines does not support YAML pipelines with other git at this moment.

There is an user voice [Support YAML pipeline with Other Git](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/t/support-yaml-pipeline-with-other-git/791462) about it, you could vote it and add your feedback.

As workaround, you could add command line task then using the git command line to clone the source from the self-hosted Gitea server.